# My Transaction is pending for over 12h now

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions

My transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4de45e4e0bd5d3f37d6c2a8f9b065014bb278f73ac8df466e96603f517366f33 is pending now for over 12h. Is there anything wrong with it? Is there a risk to lose the Coin?

Thanks,
Lars

Answer (score 2):

Lastly the ethereum network has been a bit cloagged due to massive amount of transactions. At this time there's still around 13 000 transactions pending.

As it appears, regarding the [transaction](https://www.etherchain.org/tx/0x4de45e4e0bd5d3f37d6c2a8f9b065014bb278f73ac8df466e96603f517366f33), your transaction have great probability to take long long time to get processed as apparently you provided very very low fees ( 1GWei ) and as the network is highly requested.

Before making transactions i recommend you to usually check the network load before sending, that way you can evaluate the amount of fees you want to put in order to have transactions fast processed.

Also, i wouldn't recommend to put such low fees, around 10 GWei is a good amount on low load times of the networks and if you're able to wait a bit, 20-40 GWei on the same conditions if you want your transaction to be processed fast.

If the transaction ends cancelled by the network the ETH or the token you've been trying to move will be refunded to the original address that made the transaction.

EDIT : To check the pending transactions you can follow this link https://etherscan.io/txsPending